# How to display Google sign-in button using HTML

Tags: html, oauth, google-api, google-signin

```html
<html>
       <head>      
          <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
          <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_CLIENT_ID_ON_GOOGLE_DEV.apps.googleusercontent.com">
          <!-- To integrate Google Sign-in -->
          <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
          <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

It is not displayed.
What's wrong with this HTML snippet? Do I have to do something else to display the Google sign-in button?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an elegant solution I came up with using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com).
[image: Google sign-in button]

#### Code

```
<div class="col s12 m6 offset-m3 center-align">
    <a class="oauth-container btn darken-4 white black-text" href="/users/google-oauth/" style="text-transform:none">
        <div class="left">
            <img width="20px" style="margin-top:7px; margin-right:8px" alt="Google sign-in" 
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" />
        </div>
        Login with Google
    </a>
</div>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 39):

If you use [Bootstrap v4](https://getbootstrap.com/), you can get a nice-looking button like the one below with something like:[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="/users/googleauth" role="button" style="text-transform:none">
      <img width="20px" style="margin-bottom:3px; margin-right:5px" alt="Google sign-in" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" />
      Login with Google
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Minified CSS and JS -->
<link   rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: Bless you, kind sir.

Answer (score 5):

This is the most recent and good looking sign in button without any external library (credits to [mupkoo](https://codepen.io/mupkoo/pen/YgddgB)):

[image: google sign in button]

HTML:

```html
<button type="button" class="google-sign-in-button" >
  Sign in with Google
</button>

<button type="button" class="google-sign-in-button" disabled>
  Sign in with Google
</button>
```

CSS:

```css
.google-sign-in-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
        
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 42px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .04), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    
    color: #757575;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 12px 11px;
}

.google-sign-in-button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .04), 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.google-sign-in-button:active {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.google-sign-in-button:active {
    outline: none;
        box-shadow: 
        0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .04),
        0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25),
        0 0 0 3px #c8dafc;
}

.google-sign-in-button:disabled {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .04), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: you need to change the class name in the CSS file to: login-with-google-btn

Answer (score 3):

CHECK: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
  <script>
  var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        //scope: 'additional_scope'
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
          document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
              googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
        }, function(error) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
  }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #customBtn {
      display: inline-block;
      background: white;
      color: #444;
      width: 190px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: thin solid #888;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #customBtn:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    span.label {
      font-family: serif;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    span.icon {
      background: url('/identity/sign-in/g-normal.png') transparent 5px 50% no-repeat;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 42px;
      height: 42px;
    }
    span.buttonText {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-left: 42px;
      padding-right: 42px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      /* Use the Roboto font that is loaded in the <head> */
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- In the callback, you would hide the gSignInWrapper element on a
  successful sign in -->
  <div id="gSignInWrapper">
    <span class="label">Sign in with:</span>
    <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
      <span class="icon"></span>
      <span class="buttonText">Google</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="name"></div>
  <script>startApp();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that Google will discontinue their Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web in 2023, the [Google Identity Services for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

In a single line ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcFNH.png)):

```html
<a href="#"><button type="button" style="background:#4285f4; color:white; border:none; width:110px; height:40px; border-radius:3%;"><img src="https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2210/24/Google-512.png" style="width:30px; background:white; border-radius:50%;" alt=""><b style="top: -10px; left: 5px; position: relative">Google</b></button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use Foundation:

```
<div>
  <a class="hollow button primary" href="#">
    <img width="15px" style="margin-bottom:3px; margin-right:5px" alt="Google login" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png" />
    Sign in with Google
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

```html
 <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleGoogleLogin}
            >
              <img
                width="20px"
                style={{ marginBottom: "3px", marginRight: "5px" }}
                alt="Google sign-in"
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"
              />
              Login with Google
            </Button>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUU3H.png)

Comment: onClick should not be used for security reasons (inline JS, XSS)
(inline CSS should also not be used)

Comment: Hey @jasie - because these are appear to be angular calls, the CSS and JS bindings are not inline, they get converted to programmatic bindings before it gets to the browser.

Comment: Not sure this is acceptable answer to question, which makes no reference to using Angular, Handlebars, or anything like that. Just basic HTML technologies.

Comment: This looks like it it using MUI. Perhaps you should specify it?